# Deserializing a single nested field from an object in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, deserialization

I'm looking forward to deserialize the following JSON object into a single list with built-in Kotlin serialization.

```
{
   items: CustomObject[]
}
```

```
@Serializable
data class CustomObject(val name: String)
```

The thing is, I don't want my list to be accessible through a wrapper object just for the sake of holding the list in a single field, which would end in something like that: `CustomObjectList.items[]`

Is there a way of specifying to deserialize the `items` field here directly into a `List<CustomObject>`? Thank you

Comment: you can do something like `val yourlist = deserialize(yourstring).items`

Comment: Yes sure, but I would still need a mock-up object holding a `List` attribute that is of type of the items type it holds. Because I may have JSONs having different items type, it quite bother me to have 5 wrapper objects like this one but with just different items type for each.

Comment: Depending on which parser you use, you can parse to a general `JSONObject` first (no need for a custom wrapper type) and then convert your desired properties to a custom class/list

Comment: can you update the wrapper classes? If yes, you can inherit `List` by delegation